# getColumnSearchProps not working when there's a render on column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I have a table from antd where I use getColumnSearchProps to search for a data by column but when I do this with a column that has a render method the data is not showing and when I put the getColumnSearchProps above the render method the data shows but there's no value when I search for something. Here's the code and I hope someone can help me find a fix. Thanks.

```
const daily_sales = [
{
  title: "Agent",
  key: "agent",
  render: (item) => <p>{ item.username } </p>,
  ...getColumnSearchProps("agent"),
  
},
{
  title: "Sales",
  key: "sales",
  render: (item) => {
    return (
      <p>
        {
          calculateWinnersAndWinnings(
            daily_bets?.serverConfigs,
            daily_bets?.results,
            item.bets
          ).totalSales
        }
      </p>
    );
  },
  ...getColumnSearchProps("sales"),
}];
```

And here's the code for the getColumnSearchProps:

```
const getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
filterDropdown: ({
  setSelectedKeys,
  selectedKeys,
  confirm,
  clearFilters,
}) => (
  <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
    <Input
      ref={searchInput}
      placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
      value={selectedKeys[0]}
      onChange={(e) =>
        setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
      }
      onPressEnter={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
      style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
    />
    <Space>
      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
        icon={<SearchOutlined />}
        size="small"
        style={{ width: 90 }}
      >
        Search
      </Button>
      <Button
        onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters)}
        size="small"
        style={{ width: 90 }}
      >
        Reset
      </Button>
    </Space>
  </div>
),
filterIcon: (filtered) => (
  <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
),
onFilter: (value, record) =>
  record[dataIndex]
    ? record[dataIndex]
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(value.toLowerCase())
    : "",
onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
  if (visible) {
    setTimeout(() => searchInput.current.select(), 100);
  }
},
render: (text) => (searchedColumn === dataIndex ? text : text), });
```

Comment: The `render` in your `getColumnSearchProps` will override the `render` prop you used earlier. This is because `getColumnSearchProps` is simply a helper method to build all the necessary props for the column to allow search functionality. That being said, AntD's definition of `dataIndex` is the field name that should be used to render the value for the column, for instance, the `dataIndex` for your `Agent` column is `username`. There's no need to use a custom `render` method on that column unless you really want to wrap the value in `p` tags.

Comment: In addition, your `Sales` column uses a custom `render` method so AntD's `handleSearch` will be insufficient in performing the search on your `Sales` column.

Comment: How will I reconstruct my code that will perform the necessary function on the `Sales` part? I don't know how to render a data that's not from the database.

Comment: Well, you don't have a choice when it comes to using `render` on your `Sales` column. However, you'll have to write your own custom `handleSearch` method for your `Sales` column since you're rendering with `calculateWinnersAndWinnings(...)`.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr thank you for the response sir. I'll try to create my own custom method then.